# Can I run a gas pipe in front of my electric meter pedestal?

Tags: electrical, gas, building-regulations

I want to run gas pipe to my patio for a gas grill. I'll be connecting to the grill with a quick connect hose. I would be starting back by the air conditioner and would like to come as far around the corner of the house as possible. It will be just below the brick anchored into the foundation. Can I go around the steel electric meter box? If not I'd at least like to get around the corner so the hose doesn't have to be at 90 degrees around the corner.

[image: Corner of house]

Comment: I'd like to go past the pedestal and then another 15 feet, then I could use a shorter hose. Mostly personal preference of not having a hose laying on the patio.

Comment: I don't believe there are clearance requirements for inaccessible cabinets, but I'll let a sparky answer.

Comment: as long you maintain 3 foot working access clearance to the panel

Comment: The question is whether this would qualify as an obstruction. (How large _would_ an object have to be before it is?)

Comment: What a user does with a hose is up to them. Only thing *you're* installing is a quick disconnect; the hose is not part of the obstruction equation. - Put it so it doesn't get dripped on by the water. And come out somewhere right next to all the other penetrations. - Where you're storing chairs and the outdoor box: that's where the grill goes. There's two old holes to the left of the enclosure; pick one. - I'd do the top one so it could be a 90 to a valve to a connect, pointing down so that it can drip. - 50 feet of flexible gas line laying in a planter bed? That's worse.

Comment: Incoming gas is way over there... If you're not going to tear open the basement ceiling... I'd do hard pipe along the house and then turn, but then you're on the wrong (to the right of) side of way too much going on, and where the spigot and the gutter drips. - Elbow around the house below the downspout discharge, then turn back up to get right between the spigot and the enclosure. Make it point down, and don't forget the drop leg.

Comment: Working space?!?!? +1. Do w/e you want, wh/e you want, as long as you leave me a place to stand, occupied only by things on wheels and disconnectable. - "Can I run a *hard pipe* gas line in front of my electric meter pedestal?" IDK about *can*, but just don't. A flexible... specifically, *quick connect*... line? can prob do w/e as long as it isn't across a driveway.

Comment: Have you considered running hardpipe buried past the pedestal?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel are you referring to polyethylene? I didn't consider it because it needs to be pretty deep and where the gas exits the house is about 30' away, so a lot of digging. If you're referring to steel I thought steel wasn't allowed underground. I wouldn't be opposed to going under the pavers if I don't have to go too deep.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose -- no, steel's still permitted for underground gas pipe AIUI